# How to create a photo album on flickR iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flickr

I am new to iOS. I am working on an application where I want to upload photo on `flickr`. I am using *Objective flickr Library*. I have authenticated the user as well as succeeded in uploading images on flickr. But I am facing a lot of problem on creating a photo set within `flickr`. I have tried it for many days. I tried photo submitter code a also *flickrkit* but I  am not able to do it. I also went through the *flickr api* but I am unable to get enough help. Can anyone please help me with this part.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: i want to create a photo album on flickr. using the api method flickr.photosets.create . but i am not clear how to do it.

Comment: You need to narrow it, at this stage it sounds like you don't know how to call the method.

Comment: but there is no in built method in objective flickr. can u explain how to do it

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.create.html) seems plain and simple, did you try to implement such request ? Take a look at the `RandomPublicPhoto` [Examples](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr) project, in the same way it calls `flickr.photos.getRecent` you can call `flickr.photosets.create`, but of course you need `write` authorisation.

Comment: HEY, Thanks for the hint. just wanted to ask a last question flickr.photos.getRecent has optional parameters where was flickr.photosets.create had required params . can u tell me how should i pass them using NSDictionary?

Comment: Again, it's to broad to ask. You can get the values from anywhere, it doesn't really matter. Try to follow an example, if you have difficulties - feel free to create a proper detailed question, preferably with your code and explanation of what is not clear.